# VB Background Worker Cancel RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if you could advise on cancelling a RunWorkerCompleted routine if the DoWork routine has no reason for it to do so..

```
Private Sub bgwNotifications_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwNotifications.DoWork

    'Do database Work to see if there are results

End Sub

Private Sub bgwNotifications_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwNotifications.RunWorkerCompleted

   'Show message based on results

End Sub`
```

At the moment I pass an argument which if is 0 then no code is executed in the RunWorkerCompleted routine.  Is this the way or is there an option to cancel in the DoWork which does not run the RunWorkerCompleted routine at all?

Thank you for your help and advice..

Derek.

Comment: Is it possible to not call DoWork if passing in zero?

Comment: If you don't want DoWork to do any work then there is no point at all in starting the worker.  Otherwise always favor setting e.Cancel = True in DoWork.  You get that back in RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: Hi Benno..  No the DoWork 'creates' the 0

Comment: Hi Hans..  So I can get the e.cancelled in the RunWorkerCompleted and exit the sub, but not not run the RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: The only way to not not not run RunWorkerCompleted is by unsubscribing the event.  Don't do that, use e.Cancelled to know what happened.  You must also always check e.Error to discover if any exceptions were raised in DoWork.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have to have a DoWork to see if there is a result..

Comment: Thank you Hans..  fab help..

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so I can assign it..